# Physical interpretation of TFTs

Tags: condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, history, topological-field-theory, category-theory

**1. Defining TFTs**

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $\mathbb k$ be a field.

In my lecture I was introduced to TFTs using the following definition going back to Atiyah (around 1988):

> A $n$-dimensional, oriented TFT is a symmetric monoidal functor $$Z: Cob_n \rightarrow vect(\mathbb k).$$

The cobordism category $C=Cob_n$ is defined as follows:

> - Objects are $(n-1)$-dimensional closed, smooth oriented manifolds.
> - A morphism from $M \in Obj(C)$ to $N\in Obj(C) $ is a certain equivalence class of $n$-bordisms from $M \in Obj(C)$ to $N \in Obj(C).$
> - A $n$-bordism from $M \in Obj(C)$ to $N \in Obj(C)$ is a tuple $(B, M, N, \phi_B)$ with $B$ a $n$-dimensional smooth oriented manifold with boundary (empty ir non-empty) together with an orientation preserving diffeomorphism $\phi_B: \overline M \coprod N \rightarrow \partial B$. Here, $\overline M$ denotes the manifold $M$ with opposite orientation.
> - We call two bordisms $(B, M, N, \phi_B)$ and $(B', M, N, \phi_{B'})$ equivalent if there exists an orientation preserving diffeomorphism $\phi$ such that $\phi \circ \phi_B= \phi_{B'}$. One checks that this defines indeed an equivalence relation on all $n$-bordisms from $M$ to $N$ for given $M,N \in Obj(C)$.
> - Composition of bordisms is defined by "gluing along the common boundary." (A formal exposition of "gluing along a boundary" can apparently be found in Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*.) For a given $M \in Obj(C)$ the identity morphism is given by the cylinder $(M \times [0,1], M, M)$.
> - One checks that this defines a category. In particular, one shows that the composition is well-defined, i.e. independent of the choice of representative.
> - The disjoint union of manifolds endows $C$ with the structure of a monoidal category. (The monoidal unit is given by the empty set considered as a $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold. Associator, as well as left and right unit constraint are defined appropriately.)

**2. My background**

I am a mathematics undergraduate student with very little background in physics.
Apparently, TFT's have a strong relation to physics, in particular condensed matter physics and dynamics. Wikipedia even states that "TFT's were inveted by physicists."

**3. Question**

- What are interpretations and applications of TFTs in physics?

EDIT: Motivating my question is the following statement from my (maths) lecture notes. After a study of TFTs in dimension 1 the notes propose "In physical language, we have a quantum mechanical system which has only ground states and is thus trivial Hamiltonian. Then the only invariant of the system is the degeneracy $dim(V)$ of the space of ground states."

Comment: Google might already give you numerous (introductory) papers/courses on this.

Comment: Maybe. However, an answer might give recommendations for what to read. I am convinced that someone knowledgable recommending me something is better, than me reading all sorts of papers without clear guidance (because not knowing what is relevant). Besides, I am more looking for an overview. Haven't found a paper that gives that.

Comment: And is there any subfield within physics that you are mostly interested in? Condensed matter physics, high energy physics, string theory, ...

Comment: I edited the question. I suppose, it is quantum mechanics and/or string theory.